# How to run several Laravel queued jobs at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, supervisord

I have a system running several kinds of jobs (Laravel 5.1 queues). I use database queue driver.

Supervisor makes sure 3 'instances' of `queue:work` are running as a daemon all the time.

`ps aux | grep queue` confirms this - three processes are waiting for jobs.

Sometimes I can see several job (without delay) records in the database table, but always only one of them has the `reserved` flag set to 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Why 3 daemon workers are not taking care of other jobs in the queue?

How can I make sure more than one job can be done at the same time?

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a job that sleeps for 15 seconds and then dispatches three new jobs (same class).

I ran this on my dev server and it worked. Three jobs were reserved at the same time. Once one of them is dealt with - another is taken from the queue and reserved. The behaviour one would expect.

Finally I ran the same situation on my production server and it did not work. One reserved job at once even though the environment is similar, three queue:work processes live etc.

I then asked supervisord to restart the workers and it started working as well.

So: it does work this way. The problem is I don't know what might have been causing the issue I had and when does it happen? How do I avoid this and how do I know if it's fine now?

Comment: How long do you see them in their unreserved state?

Comment: Basically until the reserved one is finished. So usually 20-30 seconds